# How to Use Internationalization with element-react

Tags: reactjs, internationalization

I've created a react application using create-react-app, and installed element-react as a dependency. I followed the instructions stated [here](https://elemefe.github.io/element-react/#/en-US/i18n) to use internationalization -- specifically adding these lines of code to what I think is the entry file (App.js):

```
import { i18n } from 'element-react'
import locale from 'element-react/src/locale/lang/en'

i18n.use(locale);
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. The other approach stated is using webpack but I don't want to do that. How do I make internationalization work with element-react? What is the entry file in a react application?

Comment: Typically you'll have an `index.js` which is your entry file. Are you doing the imports of the en locale at `index.js`?

Comment: I was doing it at `App.js`. I tried doing it at `index.js` but it still didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it did work when I placed the il8n code in `index.js`. It just doesn't seem to work for tables when they don't have data. The workaround for that is to set the `emptyText` property of the `Table` component.

Comment: in 2020 still this is the solution :)